# VBA: microsoft access database engine could not find the object (SQL query worksheet table)

Tags: sql, excel, adodb, vba

I am getting the following error message, on the line  `rs.Open strSQL, cn` , when trying to do a SQL select statement against a table range in an Excel spreadsheet:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object
>   'Sheet1$A1:NC3'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its
>   name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$A1:NC3' is not a local
>   object, check your network connection or contact the server
>   administrator

I have run through the various Stack Overflow side bar suggestions for similar questions, and let Google have a run at it, but i have still not resolved this.

1. The object is local - check
2. Workbook is the current open workbook which is saved to the desktop -check
3. Network connection fine - check

**Observations**

1. Putting the SQL string as `"Select * from [Sheet1$];"` works fine.
2. Extend that, by adding the range reference, and the error comes back i.e. `"Select * from [Sheet1$A1:NC3];"` does not work.
3. As noted in comments, up to column IV i.e. `[Sheet1$A1:IV3]` is ok; column IW onward, and error message is back.

**Note**: `Debug.Print` confirms

1. `ListObjects("Table1").Range.Address` as `$A$1:$NC$3`
2. `rngAddress` is `[Sheet1$A1:NC3];`

Can anyone please spot what i have done incorrectly? Or suggest a workaround so i can still use this range (and preferably **not** select the entire sheet)

Here is the full code:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub TestSQL()
    'Tools > references > Microsoft ActiveX Object Library

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCon As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
           & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

    Dim rngAddress As String

    rngAddress = "[" & wsSource.Name & "$" & Replace(wsSource.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Address, "$", "") & "];"

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & rngAddress

    rs.Open strSQL, cn

End Sub
```

Environment: Windows 8, Excel 2016 64 bit.

Comment: I bet that using `[Sheet1$A1:IV3]` (or perhaps only up to IU3?) will also work, and I bet that it is going to be a bug like in the first SO question I ever raised.

Comment: @YowE3K Upto IV3 did work!! So no resolution?

Comment: I think it is just something wrong with the conversion from the old format Excel files to new format - Microsoft probably forgot to change something from an Integer to a Long.  (My issue was it not recognising ranges that extended beyond row 65536 **unless** the range started at row 1.)  So column IV was the old "last column".

Comment: My company raised the incident with Microsoft (about a year ago) - still no resolution.

Comment: Makes sense to me now. Thank you. If you post this as answer i will accept. Do you think i should just work with selecting the entire sheet then?

Comment: P.S.  If someone comes up with a solution, I will be interested to know about it - it might help me too.  (I still have dummy code in my query macros that copies the relevant range to a new workbook and then does the query on that.)

Comment: Yes, I would work with the entire sheet if you can.  And I'll hold off on posting a "bad luck, it won't work" answer just in case someone has an actual solution.  (I'm only **guessing** that it is related to my, still unresolved, issue.)

Comment: @YowE3K Ok. Pretty good guess though i suspect as it works right up until i go one column over from IV.

Comment: Yeah - it certainly makes it look like an "oops" if IV works and IW doesn't.  (Anyway, I'm calling it a night now - another reason I don't want to post an answer at the moment - I'm too tired. :D)

Comment: As soon as I closed my eyes I suddenly had another thought - it might be that ADODB is limited to 256 columns.  Check whether you are getting back all the columns when you use just a basic sheet address, or whether you are only getting back the first 256 columns.  (And now I'm going back to bed - if I have any other bright ideas they will have to wait until tomorrow.)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look.

Comment: Col IV is column number 256. That's the maximum number of fields an Access table can have.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Can i expand this using a different engine?

Comment: @QHarr Most engines like SQL Sever, Oracle support more fields, and with Access you can workaround the limitations by using passthru queries, since AFAIK, linked tables will only show the 256 (or 255?) first columns.